# Cannot delete last char of StringBuffer String

Tags: android, string, stringbuffer

I am facing a strange(for me) problemm of not being able to delete the last char of a stringbuffer string. I am building an app in which i have many checkboxes and i want to take multiple values so thats why i used the stringbuffer to append the checkboxes names.

Code:

```
int length = iceCreamPreference.length();
                if (length>0){
                    iceCreamPreference = iceCreamPreference.deleteCharAt(length - 1);
                }
                Toast.makeText(SweetsLayoutActivity.this,
                        "Quantity: " + quantityNumberFinal +
                                "\nIce Cream Flavors: " + iceCreamPreference.toString() +
                                "\nIce Scream Scoops: " + quantityIceCreamNumberFinal +
                                "\nSyrups: " + syrupPreference.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Where i build the StringBuffer:

```
private void checkWhatIceCreamSelected() {
        iceCreamPreference = new StringBuffer();
        if (chocolate.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(chocolate.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (strawberry.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(strawberry.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (vanilla.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(vanilla.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (banana.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(banana.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (cookies.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(cookies.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (pistachio.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(pistachio.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (cheeseCake.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(cheeseCake.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (oreo.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(oreo.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (mango.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(mango.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (caramel.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(caramel.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (pineapple.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(pineapple.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }
        if (sorbet.isChecked()){
            iceCreamPreference.append(sorbet.getText().toString() + ", ");
        }


    }
```

The Result:

[HERE](http://imgur.com/MP0RGID)

I would like to have the last "," comma removed.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Try with iceCreamPreference = iceCreamPreference.substring(0, iceCreamPreference.length()-1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last char in the your StringBuffer will be a space, so you need to delete the last two characters to get rid of the final comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comma before the name and put a logic so that it doesn't append comma before first data entry. So code will be

Declare a boolean variable

```
 boolean comma=false;
```

Then do code like following

```
    private void checkWhatIceCreamSelected() {
    iceCreamPreference = new StringBuffer();



    if (chocolate.isChecked()){
        if(comma!=false)
        {
        iceCreamPreference.append( ", ");
        }
        iceCreamPreference.append(chocolate.getText().toString());
        comma=true;
    }
      //do same for all other if 

}
```